# Qt throws error with working code when in its own binary

Tags: c++, qt

I have written this program by itself and it works fine, but when imported to a Qt project as a header file it throws an error with the code that otherwise works.
Error:
[image: error thrown from qt creator debug]

This is the header file

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>

//global vars
FILE *pFile;
char * buffer;
long lSize;

std::basic_stringstream<char> e_lfanew() {
pFile = fopen("hello.exe", "r");

//get file size
fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_END);
long lSize = ftell(pFile);
rewind(pFile);

//alloc memory
buffer = (char *) malloc(sizeof(char) * lSize);

//read file to memory
auto result = fread(buffer, 1, lSize, pFile);

auto e_lfanew = (unsigned char *) malloc(4);
fseek(pFile, 0x3c, SEEK_SET);
fread(e_lfanew, 0x1, 0x4, pFile);
std::stringstream pe_offset;
for(size_t i=0; i<4; i++){
    std::cout << std::hex << (int)e_lfanew[i];
    pe_offset << std::hex << (int)e_lfanew[i];
}
std::cout << pe_offset.rdbuf();

return pe_offset;
}
```

This is the qt mainwindow.c file (the one with the functions for button press that causes error)

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include "e_lfanew.h"

 MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent)
     : QMainWindow(parent)
     , ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
 {
     ui->setupUi(this);
 }

 MainWindow::~MainWindow(){
     delete ui;
 }

 void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked(){
     QString e_lfanew_value = QString::fromStdString(e_lfanew().str());
     ui->label_2->setText(e_lfanew_value);
 }
```

Comment: Be careful. It's not from `Qt`'s binaries. It is from `kernel`. Therefore, I think the problem is from `e_lfanew` function

Comment: Why not use `fstream` instead of opening the file with `fopen` or use `QFile` if you are going to use `Qt` in your project.

Comment: If `fopen()` fails you get a `nullptr`. Calling `fseek()` with a `nullptr` might be good for your failed `assert()`. (Not sure, but quite sure.) You really should always test whether file open succeeded, especially for the C file API.

Comment: And btw. on MS Windows, reading binary files should always be done explicitly: `fopen(file_name, "rb")` (or `std::ifstream(file_name, std::ios::binary)`). Otherwise, you may not get exactly what you really have in the file. ;-)

Answer (score 1):

Your program doesn't throw an error from `Qt` binaries but from `minkernel/crts/ucrt/src/appcrt/stdio/fseek.cpp`. Hence I think the problem is from your code when you try to `fseek`. Your code has some problems and a big problem is that you don't check the file descriptor to be not null before you use it.

From `fopen()` documentation you can read.

> If the file is successfully opened, the function returns a pointer to a `FILE` object that can be used to identify the stream on future operations.
>   Otherwise, a null pointer is returned.
>   On most library implementations, the `errno` variable is also set to a system-specific error code on failure.

This means that you probably can get a null pointer in your `pFile` variable after opening the file. Try adding the following line.

```
std::basic_stringstream<char> e_lfanew() {
pFile = fopen("hello.exe", "r");

if (pFile == nullptr)          // or simply if (!pFile)
    // Cannot open file. Handle the situation

fseek(pFile, 0, SEEK_END);
long lSize = ftell(pFile);
rewind(pFile);
```

### Edit 1

As *@Scheff* mentioned in the comment, on MS Windows, reading binary files should always be done explicitly: `fopen(file_name, "rb") (or std::ifstream(file_name, std::ios::binary))`. Otherwise, you may not get exactly what you really have in the file.